# Remove part from CompositonContainer

Tags: .net, mef

Wen using a composition batch to remove a part from the container, how does one get a reference to the part that needs to be removed? The compositon batch remove method takes a composablepart. The AddPart method also takes a composablepart type parameter but has an over load (extension method) that takes in an object and uses AttributedModelServices.CreatePart to get a composablepart. I tried using the AttributedModelServices.CreatePart on the reference I get from the container, and then using that for the remove method but it didn't remove it from the container.

I can save the reference that's returned by the original AddPart call, but that means I'd have to persist that reference throughout the application. Not what I want to do. I've see examples of looping over the container's parts but that seems hacky to me.

How do I get the container to return what I need.

**Psuedo code**

```
CompositionBatch batch = new CompositionBatch([] { Part1, Part2 }, []{});
Container.Compose(batch);

var partRef = Container.GetExport<Part2>();

batch = new CompositionBatch();
batch.RemovePart(partRef);

container.Compose(batch);
```